# Make FocusManager wait until databinding is complete?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to get a WPF application to set its initial focus to a `TextBox` that is inside of a grid. That `TextBox` has its `Text` property databound to a view controller that may or may not already have text set. When this focus is set and the `TextBox` already has existing text, I want that text to be selected so you can immediately edit it just by typing.

I can accomplish this by doing a `Focus()` call inside of the `Loaded` event of the `Window` as follows:

```
public void HighlightTextOnFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var senderBox = (TextBox)sender;
    senderBox.SelectionStart = 0;
    senderBox.SelectionLength = senderBox.Text.Length;
}

private void EditEntryView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TotalHoursBox.Focus();
}
```

My question is how to accomplish the same thing without using code-behind and instead do it inside the XAML. I have tried using `FocusManager` but that tries to set focus before the databinding is complete, causing my `HighlightTextOnFocus` method to be called **before** the text is actually set, accomplishing nothing.

Is there a way to force the `FocusManager` to wait until databinding is complete?

Comment: Have you tried using it in an EventTrigger just attached to the Loaded event? Sounds equivalent and done in just xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Attached Behavior pattern for this. It will look like:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" local:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior.IsEnabled="True" />`

SelectAllTextBoxBehavior code available [here](http://pastebin.com/UcUyKU58)

Or use Blend SDK, details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/argumentnullexceptionblogpost/archive/2013/04/12/a-simple-selectall-behavior-for-textboxes.aspx)